# how to bind cPanel WGSI to an seperated aiohttp server

Tags: python-3.x, cpanel, aiohttp

Hey guys I've just been trying to deploy my aiohttp+socketIo application into cPanel host which **Supports** python, and I've figured out cPanel uses a pre-build WSGI server itself, it routes all URLs to the function that you choose in the python app settings.

currently I'm running my server like this:
`web.run_app(app, port=880, host="localhost")`
and it works perfectly when I run it solo, but when I try to use it in the cPanel, nothing happens. I guessed that that's because of host, so I changed it a lot but it didn't work either.

how can I bind these to work together?

Comment: Hi there, please look at this guide [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I've corrected it, thanks.